# audio.fade() is not turning on

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am working on a sound on and off switch but when i use "audio.setVolume( 0.0 )" and "audio.setVolume( 0.7 )" it works but when i am trying to use the "fade" & "fadeOut" function it turns the sound off like i want it but no on again.

```
function onOFF(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        if  sound == 1 then
                sound = sound + 1 
                            audio.fadeOut({ channel=setVolume, time=500 } )
                switchoff()
        elseif  sound == 2 then
                sound = sound - 1
                audio.fade({ channel=setVolume, time=500, volume=0.7 } ) 
                switchon()
        end     
    end
end
```

I can see the reason for this, any help ?

---

```
function switchon()
    screenGroup = self.view
    SwitchOff = display.newImage("soundISon.png")
    screenGroup:insert(SwitchOff)
    SwitchOff.x = 50; SwitchOff.y = 600
    transition.to( SwitchOff, { time=700, y=465, transition=easing.inOutExpo } )
    transition.to( SwitchOn, { time=500, y=500, transition=easing.inOutExpo } )
    SwitchOff:addEventListener("touch", onOFF)
end
```

Comment: can you add your switchon() function on your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535772/audio-fade-is-not-turning-on/17538241#17538241

Comment: You know, you can edit your own question.

Comment: I edited my answers, please review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fade the volume, you are changing the volume of the channel. This value is persistent and **it is your responsibility to reset the volume on the channel if you want to use the channel again later**.

You need to set again the volume of the channel by using `audio.setVolume()`

**Addition:**
`audio.fadeOut()` - This stops a playing sound in a specified amount of time and fades to min volume while doing it. The audio will stop at the end of the time and the channel will be freed.

So I think you need to play the sound again and set the volume to **0.0** before you use the `audio.fade()`

```
function onOFF(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        if  sound == 1 then
                sound = sound + 1 
                audio.fadeOut({ channel=setVolume, time=500 } )
                switchoff()
        elseif  sound == 2 then
                sound = sound - 1

                audio.play( yourSound, {channel=setVolume, loops=-1}) -- Like this
                audio.setVolume( 0.0, { channel=setVolume } )
                audio.fade({ channel=setVolume, time=500, volume=0.7 } ) 
                switchon()
        end     
    end
end
```

[Reference](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/audio/fadeOut.html)

Comment: there is this other strange thing when i use "audio.setVolume( 0.0 )" and "audio.setVolume( 0.7 )" it turns all the sound off and on including the other screens but then i use 'fade' it only turns the sound off in the curent screen.

Comment: You can add a channel you want to change on `audio.setVolume(0.7,{channel=setVolume})`

Comment: yes but 'audio.setVolume' or 'setVolume' is supposed to be the master volume control so in theory if you fade it down to '0.0' all sound channels should be at '0.0' right?

Comment: Yes that is correct, if you want to fadeOut or fade all channels, you must remove the channel options like this `audio.fade({time=500, volume=0.7 })` and `audio.fadeOut({time=500})`